# For how many values of $\theta$ such that $0<\theta<360$ do we have $\cos \theta = 0.1$?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, trigonometry

For how many values of $\theta$ such that $0<\theta<360$ do we have $\cos \theta = 0.1$? (Note that $\theta$ is a measure in radians, not degrees!)

---

The period of $\cos(x)$ is $2\pi,$ $114pi = 358.14,$ so $\cos(x)$ repeats $114/2 = 57$ times. So the answer is $57 \cdot 2 = 114,$ but since cosine is split over y axis on the first period, we add $1$ to $114,$ and get $115.$
Is my answer correct?  Thanks for any confirmation or correction!

Comment: For that range of $\;\theta\;$ you give a complete turn around the trigonometric circle (except the end points which we don't care now about) . How many times **exactly** is *every possible* value for $\;\cos\theta\;$ attained while turning around?

Comment: @DonAntonio  Twice, since there are $2\pi$ radians in each rotation.  And also, is $115$ the correct asnwer to the problem?  Thanks!

Comment: Exactly: only twice. As you seem to be using degrees, I get that happens at $\;84.26^\circ\;,\;\;360-89.43=275.74^\circ\;$ degrees.  In radians I get  $\;\pm 1.47\;$ radians.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well my calculator says $\arccos 0,1 = 1,4706289... + 57 \cdot 2\pi = 359,61...\ $ so you are right.